# Laravel not booting trait/authing user in unit tests

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I can't figure out if Laravel is failing to boot my model trait, or is simply not seeing the user as being authed within the trait.

All of this code works perfectly fine when I test my app manually, but when I run unit tests I am getting a bunch of errors.

Here is the trait I've added to `App\User` and a few other models:

```
trait HasCompany
{
    public static function bootHasCompany()
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            static::creating(function ($model) {
                $model->company_id = auth()->user()->company_id;
            });
            static::addGlobalScope('company_id', function (Builder $builder) {
                $builder->where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id);
            });
        }
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
}
```

The purpose of this trait is to automatically add the logged in users `company_id` to any models they create, and restrict their access only to models they have created. I should mention that all `App\User`'s have a `company_id` set in the database.

So as I've said, when I attempt to create a model when logged into my app everything works great. The trait works perfectly. However, unit tests don't seem to care for this trait. Here is an example test that does not work:

```
class RoleTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker;

    public $user;

    public function setup()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->user = App\User::create([
            'company_id' => $faker->randomNumber(),
            'name' => $this->faker->firstName,
            'email' => $this->faker->email,
            'password' => $this->faker->password,
        ]);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $this->user->delete();
    }

    public function testAdd()
    {
        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->json('POST', 'roles/add', [
            '_token' => csrf_token(),
            'name' => $this->faker->word,
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200)->assertJson(['flash' => true]);
    }
}
```

I'm getting a 500 response instead of a 200 response because the model should automatically be obtaining the `company_id` from `$this->user`, but it is not. This is only happening for unit tests.

Here is the model code:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    use HasCompany;

    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'name'];  
}
```

Why aren't the unit tests booting the trait properly? It seems like `actingAs` doesn't work for authorization within traits, or is failing to boot it's traits entirely.

Comment: Where do you call `bootHasCompany`? Note that boot is probably called before the user is authenticated

Comment: If you remove `if (auth()->check())` or move it to the closures and call `bootHasCompany` in laravel's `boot`. Your code should work.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov If you have a static function on your trait, named boot[TraitName], it will be executed as the boot() function would on an Eloquent model. So there is no need to call it manually

Answer (score 4):

In your unit tests, the user model is first booted when the user is created by the setup function. At that time, no user is authenticated (as actingAs follows later). So, the `auth()->check()` only happens once when the user is created.

I think instead of checking if authenticated once (during boot), you should check if authenticated during the user creation.

Remove `if(auth()->check())` from bootHasCompany and add it inside the Eloquent event closures like so:

```
static::creating(function ($model) {
    if(auth()->check())
    {
        $model->company_id = auth()->user()->company_id;
    }
});
static::addGlobalScope('company_id', function (Builder $builder) {
    if(auth()->check())
    {
        $builder->where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id);
    }
});
```